# How can I use emacs in the TopCoder Arena?

Tags: emacs

TCEMacs looks like what I want, but I don't see installation instructions, and I can't launch the jar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about version 0.2 of [this](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~tmal/tc_emacs/index.html) plugin.

If that is correct, have you actually bothered looking at the contents of the `tc_emacs-0.2.tar.gz` file offered for download? Besides the .jar file it contains a README that clearly has installation instructions:

> Install gnuserv. You can download it from
>   http://meltin.net/hacks/emacs/ or just use a package if your GNU/Linux
>   distribution provides one. The gnuserv must be working before
>   launching the Arena. The easiest way is to put
>
> (gnuserv-start)
>
> in your .emacs file. The gnuserv will then be started together with
>   Emacs.
>
> Make sure that you have Emacs/W3 Browser installed in Emacs. You can
>   check it by typing `M-x w3 '.
>
> Put topcoder.el and TCEmacs.jar in some directory. The topcoder.el
>   file should be loaded before using Emacs in the Arena. You can do that
>   by typing `M-x load-library  /path/to/topcoder.el ' or you
>   can just place
>
> (load-library "/path/to/topcoder.el")
>
> or, to load the file only when it is needed:
>
> (autoload 'topcoder-set-problem "/path/to/topcoder.el")
>
> in your .emacs file. I had some problems with autoloading, though. The
>   keymap in the TopCoder mode did not sometimes work and I had to reload
>   topcoder.el manually.
>
> Make a work directory and set the topcoder-directory variable to its
>   name. By default it points to a directory named topcoder in your home
>   directory.
>
> Launch the Arena applet and choose Options/Editor/Add. Type in a name
>   (e.g. Emacs), TCEmacs as the entry point and a path to the TCEmacs.jar
>   file in the ClassPath field.
>
> Now choose a problem to solve. If everything went fine, you should see
>   two new Emacs windows, one with a problem statement and the second one
>   with a source code template.